# How to set up swagger ui with working anchors

Tags: swagger-ui

I am using https://app.swaggerhub.com/ to develop my api endpoints. I have set it up in `webroot/swagger` folder. This folder contains

```
favicon-16x16.png  
oauth2-redirect.html  
swagger-ui-bundle.js.map  
swagger-ui.js                    
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js.map
favicon-32x32.png  
swagger.json          
swagger-ui.css            
swagger-ui.js.map
index.html         
swagger-ui-bundle.js  
swagger-ui.css.map        
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
```

What i do is export json_resolved for `app...` to my repo and it loads fine. problem is when i click on an endpoint and want to load the endpoint specifically on first load. for example
loading `http://exampledomain.com/swagger/#/giant/addCm` on 1st load would error

```
Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

r {name: "YAMLException", reason: "end of the stream or a document separator is expected", mark: o, message: "end of the stream or a document separator is expec…  box-sizing: border-box;↵                      ^", stack: "YAMLException: end of the stream or a document sep…lreply.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:51:29161)"}
name: "YAMLException"
reason: "end of the stream or a document separator is expected"
mark: o {name: null, buffer: "<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->…dow.ui = ui↵    }↵  </script>↵  </body>↵</html>↵", position: 432, line: 12, column: 18}
message: "end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 13, column 19:↵            box-sizing: border-box;↵                      ^"
stack: "YAMLException: end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 13, column 19:↵            box-sizing: border-box;↵                      ^↵    at M (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:79:71772)↵    at N (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:79:71870)↵    at Y (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:79:85578)↵    at $ (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:79:85933)↵    at Z (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:79:86083)↵    at Object.e.exports.safeLoad (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:79:86413)↵    at https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:6:6349↵    at Object.dispatch (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:1:60251)↵    at dispatch (<anonymous>:1:28545)↵    at Object.parseToJson (https://dev1.domain.com/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js:51:29161)"
__proto__: Error



openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: |
  
    # Requirements
  
      * domain Service Account
      * CORS Proxy | We can add your FQDN to the whitelist
    
  version: 2.0.0
  title: CCP API
  # put the contact info for your development or API team
  contact:
    email: m.uddin@reply.com

  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html

# tags are used for organizing operations
tags:
- name: dcsn
- name: find
- name: firewall
- name: lists
- name: services
- name: vpf
- name: cm
- name: giant



security:
  - BasicAuth: []  
  
paths:
  /iwsapi/admin/rename/comms/matrices:
    post:
      tags:
        - cm
      summary: Rename Cm
      operationId: renameCm
      description: Rename Cm
      requestBody: 
        #description: add column filters
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CmForm'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Verify Policy Flow
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cm'
        401:
          description: invalid user
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
        422:
          description: invalid input, object invalid
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
      security:
        - BasicAuth: []

components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
  headers:
    xPaginationCount:
      description: Total no. of records found.
      schema:
        type: integer
    xPaginationLimit:
      description: No. of records to limit fetch.
      schema:
        type: integer
    xPaginationOffset:
      description: Start fetch from row
      schema:
        type: integer
  schemas:
    Error:
      type: object
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          header:
            type: object
            properties:
              error:
                type: boolean
              message:
                type: string
      example:
        header:
          error: true
          message: error message if available
    CmForm:
      type: object
      required:
      - comms_matrix_id
      properties:
        comms_matrix_id:
          type: number
          example: 1
        remedy_inc:
          type: string
          description: 15 characters long, starts with AAS|INC|CRQ|TAS|RLM, continues with 12 digits
          example: AAS111111111111
        remedy_status:
          type: string
          enum: [Assigned, Cancelled, Closed, In Progress, Pending, Resolved]
          example: Assigned
        remedy_team:
          type: string
          example: team
        remedy_status_reason:
          type: string
          example: free text
    Cm:
      type: object
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          body:
            type: object
            properties:
              recordset:
                type: object
                properties:
                  record:
                    type: array
                    items: 
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        id:
                          type: number
                        service_id:
                          type: number
                        filename:
                          type: string
                        visible_lines:
                          type: number
                        aggregated_flows:
                          type: number
                        security_flows:
                          type: number
                        routing_flows:
                          type: number
                        error_flows:
                          type: number
                        security_permit:
                          type: number
                        security_deny:
                          type: number
                        security_exemption:
                          type: number
                        security_prevention:
                          type: number
                        routing_permit:
                          type: number
                        routing_deny:
                          type: number
                        routing_exemption:
                          type: number
                        routing_prevention:
                          type: number
                        routing_issues:
                          type: number
                        uploaded_by:
                          type: string
                        ts_updated:
                          type: string
                        ts_created:
                          type: string
                        frozen:
                          type: boolean
                        deleted:
                          type: boolean
                        warning_flows:
                          type: number
                        remedy_status:
                          type: string
                        remedy_inc:
                          type: string
                        cm_sox_approval_id:
                          type: number
                        remedy_team:
                          type: string
                        remedy_status_reason:
                          type: string
                  metadata:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      num_rows:
                        type: number
      example:
        body:
          recordset:
            record:
              - id:  135841
                service_id:  3
                filename:  German_Zones_Test3.xlsx
                visible_lines:  48
                aggregated_flows:  1
                security_flows:  48
                routing_flows:  1
                error_flows:  0
                security_permit:  48
                security_deny:  48
                security_exemption:  0
                security_prevention: 0
                routing_permit: 0
                routing_deny: 0
                routing_exemption: 48
                routing_prevention: 0
                routing_issues: null
                uploaded_by: kakoullim
                ts_updated: 13-Mar-20 11:55:38
                ts_created: 20-Mar-03 12:14:04
                frozen: 0
                deleted: 0
                warning_flows: 0
                remedy_status: Pending
                remedy_inc: INC123456789101
                cm_sox_approval_id: 4550
                remedy_team: null
                remedy_status_reason: null 
            metadata:
              num_rows:
                1  
  
          
schemes:
 - https
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
# basePath: /
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
host: ccp.domain.com
# basePath: /vf-ccp/ccp/1.0.0
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
basePath: /
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
servers:
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
  - description: CCP-PRODSUPP
    url: https://prodsupp.domain.com
  - description: Sytel
    url: https://dev1.domain.com
  - description: CCP-TEST
    url: https://test.domain.com
```

**/swagger/index.html**

```
...
<body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: window.location.href + "swagger.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
      })
      // End Swagger UI call region

      window.ui = ui
    }
  </script>
  </body>
...
```

Comment: Can you also post the Swagger UI configuration code (`const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({...`) from `index.html`?

Comment: @Helen added extra code from index.html